# Strange issue: deactivated Facebook friends accounts are still searchable

Tags: facebook

Several people in my Facebook friends list come up as having deactivated accounts when I try to click on them from the friends list. However, when searching for them by name, they come up with blank profile pictures and no add friend button. What does this mean?

Comment: One of these people shows up in my Messenger sidebar, and when I click on her name it says, "You are friends on Facebook."  However, clicking her name (to take me to her profile) gives me the message, "Sorry, this content isn't available right now." So confused...

Answer (score 1):

When a user deactivates their Facebook account, much of their data is hidden from public view. So while you may still see their name in your friends list, their profile picture will be blank and most of their information will probably be gone (at least, from your view). You cannot send a friend request to a deactivated account.